# SQL Server Flatten Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, crosstab

I have 3 tables:

```
tUsers
  -uid

tColors
  -colorid
  -colorname

tColors_User_Detail
  -uid_fk
  -colorid_fk
```

Users select which colors they like, and only the colors they like.  This creates records in tColors_User_Detail.  I need to flatten this out, so that each user has one record with the color from tColors as a column name, and they have a True/False value in the row for each color depending on if they had a record in tColors_User_Detail.  If the user did not have a color selected in tColors_User_Detail, it would be a False value in the specific color column.  And, if they do have a record in tColors_User_Detail for a color, it would be a true value for the corresponding color column.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide what you have tried already?

Comment: Also sample input and ouput data with few rows to explain the desired output.

Comment: Google the PIVOT operator, or indeed other pivot solutions. These are designed to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic PIVOT example with a COALESCE to show 'false' if no value is available. This assumes you have to hard-code the names of the colors for the column names.

```
DECLARE @tUsers TABLE ([uid] INT)
DECLARE @tColors TABLE ([colorid] INT, [colorname] VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @tColors_User_Detail TABLE ([uid_fk] INT, [colorid_fk] INT)
INSERT @tUsers VALUES (1),(2)
INSERT @tColors VALUES (1,'Blue'),(2,'Red'),(3,'Green')
INSERT @tColors_User_Detail VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1)

SELECT
    uid,
    COALESCE([Red], 'False') AS [Red],
    COALESCE([Blue], 'False') AS [Blue],
    COALESCE([Green], 'False') AS [Green]
FROM @tUsers U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @tColors_User_Detail CUD
        ON CUD.uid_fk = U.uid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @tColors C
        ON C.colorid = CUD.colorid_fk
    PIVOT (MAX(colorname) FOR colorname IN (
        [Red],
        [Blue],
        [Green]
    )) PVT
```

If you want to let the columns be dynamic from the colors, you'll have to use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(1000) =
    'SELECT uid'
    + (SELECT ', CASE WHEN [' + [colorname] + '] IS NOT NULL THEN ''True'' ELSE ''False'' END AS [' + [colorname] + ']' AS [text()] FROM tColors FOR XML PATH(''))
    + ' FROM tUsers  U
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tColors_User_Detail CUD
                ON CUD.uid_fk = U.uid
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tColors C
                ON C.colorid = CUD.colorid_fk
            PIVOT (MAX(colorname) FOR colorname IN ('
    + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',[' + [colorname] + ']' AS [text()] FROM tColors FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 1000)
    + ')) PVT'
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I need the color names to be pulled from the tColors table, not hard coded, as the available colors may change over time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with this.

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  The records would need to be distinct, one record per user, and the values in the fields should be True / False.  How would I modify?

Comment: The PIVOT ensures you only have 1 record per user (PIVOT has the aggregate in the statement). I updated the `SELECT` columns to use a `CASE` to determine whether just TRUE/FALSE is displayed. Hope that helps!

Comment: I expect PIVOT to make it distinct as well, but the results have multiple rows per user, equaling the number of rows they have in the tColors_User_Detail.  It appears to be just flattening out each row.  So if there are 3 records in tColors_User_Detail, it is flattening that out to have colors as the columns, and putting the true false value in the correct column, but still has 3 records.  Appears I would need to MAX each column at those point to make distinct.

Comment: Got it working by adding MAX around the case statements, and then grouping by uid after the PVT.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What flavor of SQL?

Something along the lines of:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec4e2

```
SELECT U.uid
  , C.colorid
  , C.colorname
  , ( CASE WHEN cud.uid_fk IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END ) AS ColorChosen
FROM tUsers U
FULL OUTER JOIN tColors C ON 1=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tColors_User_Detail cud ON 
  U.uid = cud.uid_fk
  AND C.colorid = cud.colorID_FK
```

EDIT: I missed the pivot for one row per user. Meeting time though. Be back in a bit.